Weird GUI boxes after hibernation
Whenever I left Ubuntu in hibernation then after that when I open Ubuntu its GUI get boxes all over.
[1

please read [ask] then [edit] accordingly.

press ctrl+alt+f3

Then what to do ?

login at console

Guide me correctly how I can fix it!
